# PHP Find All (somewhat) Unique Combinations of an Array

Tags: php, algorithm, recursion, permutation, combinations

I've been looking at PHP array permutation / combination questions all day.. and still can't figure it out :/

If I have an array like:

```
20 //key being 0    
20 //key being 1    
22 //key being 2    
24 //key being 3
```

I need combinations like:

```
20, 20, 22 //keys being 0 1 2    
20, 20, 24 //keys being 0 1 3    
20, 22, 24 //keys being 0 2 3
20, 22, 24 //keys being 1 2 3
```

The code I currently have gives me:

```
20, 22, 24
```

because it doesn't want to repeat 20... but that's what I need!

Here is the code I have. it is directly from [Php recursion to get all possibilities of strings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4279722/php-recursion-to-get-all-possibilities-of-strings/8880362#8880362)

```
function getCombinations($base,$n){

$baselen = count($base);
if($baselen == 0){
    return;
}
    if($n == 1){
        $return = array();
        foreach($base as $b){
            $return[] = array($b);
        }
        return $return;
    }else{
        //get one level lower combinations
        $oneLevelLower = getCombinations($base,$n-1);

        //for every one level lower combinations add one element to them that the last element of a combination is preceeded by the element which follows it in base array if there is none, does not add
        $newCombs = array();

        foreach($oneLevelLower as $oll){

            $lastEl = $oll[$n-2];
            $found = false;
            foreach($base as  $key => $b){
                if($b == $lastEl){
                    $found = true;
                    continue;
                    //last element found

                }
                if($found == true){
                        //add to combinations with last element
                        if($key < $baselen){

                            $tmp = $oll;
                            $newCombination = array_slice($tmp,0);
                            $newCombination[]=$b;
                            $newCombs[] = array_slice($newCombination,0);
                        }

                }
            }

        }

    }

    return $newCombs;


}
```

I've been playing around with the `($b == $lastEl)` line, with no luck

===============

Questions I've already looked at, and are not the same OR that created an out of memory error!:

- [How can I get all permutations in PHP without sequential duplicates?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12238675/how-can-i-get-all-permutations-in-php-without-sequential-duplicates)
- [Permutations - all possible sets of numbers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5506888/permutations-all-possible-sets-of-numbers)
- [Combinations, Dispositions and Permutations in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1679605/combinations-dispositions-and-permutations-in-php)
- [PHP array combinations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3742506/php-array-combinations)
- [Get all permutations of a PHP array?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10222835/get-all-combinations-of-a-php-array)
- [PHP: How to get all possible combinations of 1D array?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10834393/php-how-to-get-all-possible-combinations-of-1d-array)
- [Select only unique array values from this array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11340450/select-only-unique-array-values-from-this-array)
- [Get all permutations of a PHP array?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10222835/get-all-combinations-of-a-php-array)
- [PHP: How to get all possible combinations of 1D array?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10834393/php-how-to-get-all-possible-combinations-of-1d-array)
- [Select only unique array values from this array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11340450/select-only-unique-array-values-from-this-array)
- [How can I get all permutations in PHP without sequential duplicates?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12238675/how-can-i-get-all-permutations-in-php-without-sequential-duplicates)
- [Algorithm to return all combinations of k elements from n](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/127704/algorithm-to-return-all-combinations-of-k-elements-from-n)
- [Find combination(s) sum of element(s) in array whose sum equal to a given number](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12837431/find-combinations-sum-of-elements-in-array-whose-sum-equal-to-a-given-number)
- [Combinations, Dispositions and Permutations in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1679605/combinations-dispositions-and-permutations-in-php)
- [PHP array combinations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3742506/php-array-combinations)
- [Php recursion to get all possibilities of strings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4279722/php-recursion-to-get-all-possibilities-of-strings/8880362#8880362)
- [How to return permutations of an array in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5167726/how-to-return-permutations-of-an-array-in-php)
- [Permutations - all possible sets of numbers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5506888/permutations-all-possible-sets-of-numbers)
- [Subset-sum problem in PHP with MySQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7416401/subset-sum-problem-in-php-with-mysql)
- [Find unique combinations of values from arrays filtering out any duplicate pairs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9088963/find-unique-combinations-of-values-from-arrays-filtering-out-any-duplicate-pairs)
- [Finding all the unique permutations of a string without generating duplicates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9217839/finding-all-the-unique-permutations-of-the-string)
- [Generate all unique permutations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9415692/generate-all-unique-permutations)
- [Subset sum for exactly k integers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9839004/subset-sum-for-exactly-k-integers)

I've tried some of these algorithms with an array of 12 items, and end up running out of memory. However the algorithm that I'm currently using doesn't give me an out of memory error.... BUT.. I need those duplicates!

Comment: Please give a proper example of input data and expected output. `var_dump()` format would fit

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If you don't mind using a couple of global variables, you could do this in PHP (translated from a [version](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4061080/output-each-combination-of-an-array-of-numbers-with-javascript) in JavaScript):

```
<?PHP
$result = array(); 
$combination = array();

function combinations(array $myArray, $choose) {
  global $result, $combination;

  $n = count($myArray);

  function inner ($start, $choose_, $arr, $n) {
    global $result, $combination;

    if ($choose_ == 0) array_push($result,$combination);
    else for ($i = $start; $i <= $n - $choose_; ++$i) {
           array_push($combination, $arr[$i]);
           inner($i + 1, $choose_ - 1, $arr, $n);
           array_pop($combination);
         }
  }
  inner(0, $choose, $myArray, $n);
  return $result;
}

print_r(combinations(array(20,20,22,24), 3));
?>
```

OUTPUT:

```
Array ( [0] => Array ( [0] => 20 
                       [1] => 20 
                       [2] => 22 ) 
        [1] => Array ( [0] => 20 
                       [1] => 20 
                       [2] => 24 ) 
        [2] => Array ( [0] => 20 
                       [1] => 22 
                       [2] => 24 ) 
        [3] => Array ( [0] => 20 
                       [1] => 22 
                       [2] => 24 ) )
```

Comment: There's also a pear package available here: http://pear.php.net/package/Math_Combinatorics

Answer (score 3):

The pear package Math_Combinatorics makes this kind of problem fairly easy. It takes relatively little code, it's simple and straightforward, and it's pretty easy to read.

```
$ cat code/php/test.php
<?php
$input = array(20, 20, 22, 24);

require_once 'Math/Combinatorics.php';

$c = new Math_Combinatorics;
$combinations = $c->combinations($input, 3);
for ($i = 0; $i < count($combinations); $i++) {
  $vals = array_values($combinations[$i]);
  $s = implode($vals, ", ");
  print $s . "\n";
}
?>

$ php code/php/test.php
20, 20, 22
20, 20, 24
20, 22, 24
20, 22, 24
```

If I had to package this as a function, I'd do something like this.

```
function combinations($arr, $num_at_a_time) 
{
    include_once 'Math/Combinatorics.php';

    if (count($arr) < $num_at_a_time) {
        $arr_count = count($arr);
        trigger_error(
            "Cannot take $arr_count elements $num_at_a_time " 
            ."at a time.", E_USER_ERROR
        );
    }

    $c = new Math_Combinatorics;
    $combinations = $c->combinations($arr, $num_at_a_time);

    $return = array();
    for ($i = 0; $i < count($combinations); $i++) {
        $values = array_values($combinations[$i]);
        $return[$i] = $values;
    }
    return $return;
}
```

That will return an array of arrays. To get the text . . .

```
<?php
  include_once('combinations.php');

  $input = array(20, 20, 22, 24);
  $output = combinations($input, 3);

  foreach ($output as $row) {
      print implode($row, ", ").PHP_EOL;
  }
?>
20, 20, 22
20, 20, 24
20, 22, 24
20, 22, 24
```

Comment: why re-invent the wheel ? this is probably the best answer here, I have downloaded the pear class and included it in my project ... thanks

Answer (score 2):

Why not just use binary? At least then its simple and very easy to understand what each line of code does like this? Here's a function i wrote for myself in a project which i think is pretty neat!

```
function search_get_combos($array){
$bits = count($array); //bits of binary number equal to number of words in query;
//Convert decimal number to binary with set number of bits, and split into array
$dec = 1;
$binary = str_split(str_pad(decbin($dec), $bits, '0', STR_PAD_LEFT));
while($dec < pow(2, $bits)) {
    //Each 'word' is linked to a bit of the binary number.
    //Whenever the bit is '1' its added to the current term.
    $curterm = "";
    $i = 0;
    while($i < ($bits)){
        if($binary[$i] == 1) {
            $curterm[] = $array[$i]." ";
        }
        $i++;
    }
    $terms[] = $curterm;
    //Count up by 1
    $dec++;
    $binary = str_split(str_pad(decbin($dec), $bits, '0', STR_PAD_LEFT));
}
return $terms;
}
```

For your example, this outputs:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => 24 
        )
    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => 22 
        )
    [2] => Array
        (
            [0] => 22 
            [1] => 24 
        )
    [3] => Array
        (
            [0] => 20 
        )
    [4] => Array
        (
            [0] => 20 
            [1] => 24 
        )
    [5] => Array
        (
            [0] => 20 
            [1] => 22 
        )
    [6] => Array
        (
            [0] => 20 
            [1] => 22 
            [2] => 24 
        )
    [7] => Array
        (
            [0] => 20 
        )
    [8] => Array
        (
            [0] => 20 
            [1] => 24 
        )
    [9] => Array
        (
            [0] => 20 
            [1] => 22 
        )
    [10] => Array
        (
            [0] => 20 
            [1] => 22 
            [2] => 24 
        )
    [11] => Array
        (
            [0] => 20 
            [1] => 20 
        )
    [12] => Array
        (
            [0] => 20 
            [1] => 20 
            [2] => 24 
        )
    [13] => Array
        (
            [0] => 20 
            [1] => 20 
            [2] => 22 
        )
    [14] => Array
        (
            [0] => 20 
            [1] => 20 
            [2] => 22 
            [3] => 24 
        )
)
```

Answer (score 1):

Had the same problem and found a different and bitwise, faster solution:

```
function bitprint($u) {
    $s = array();
    for ($n=0; $u; $n++, $u >>= 1){
        if ($u&1){
            $s [] = $n;
        }
    }
    return $s;
}
function bitcount($u) {
    for ($n=0; $u; $n++, $u = $u&($u-1));
    return $n;
}
function comb($c,$n) {
    $s = array();
    for ($u=0; $u<1<<$n; $u++){
        if (bitcount($u) == $c){
            $s [] = bitprint($u);
        }
    }
    return $s;
}
```

This one generates all size m combinations of the integers from 0 to n-1, so for example
m = 2, n = 3 and calling comb(2, 3) will produce:

```
0 1
0 2
1 2
```

It gives you index positions, so it's easy to point to array elements by index.

**Edit:** Fails with input comb(30, 5). Have no idea why, anyone any idea?

Comment: You're right, this is a translation from javascript and even the javascript code fails with the same input.

Comment: It works but comb(30,5) doesn't. I think it's because it's wrong input and 30 it's too high.

Answer (score 1):

Cleaned up Adi Bradfield's sugestion using strrev and for/foreach loops, and only get unique results.

```
function search_get_combos($array = array()) {
sort($array);
$terms = array();

for ($dec = 1; $dec < pow(2, count($array)); $dec++) {
    $curterm = array();
    foreach (str_split(strrev(decbin($dec))) as $i => $bit) {
        if ($bit) {
            $curterm[] = $array[$i];
        }
    }
    if (!in_array($curterm, $terms)) {
        $terms[] = $curterm;
    }
}

return $terms;
}
```